# Starting an exe on the server

Tags: php

I want to execute an exe on the server running a PHP/ASP Web server. Can i write any php/asp file for the same that will initiate the exe on the web server. Do I need to give explicit permissions or permissions are given by default.. or is there any security hole?

Comment: What is php/asp? does that mean it runs either php or asp? also in your tag you specify asp.net, which is nothing like asp classic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to the "Can I...?" portion of the question : yes, you can.

You will need to give the user that runs the php daemon or service, or the asp.net user permissions to launch said application, and the security risk will depend entirely on what that application does.

Here's how it would work in ASP.NET:

First, make sure you put the .exe file in the App_Code folder of your project!

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.FileName = "C:\\filepath\\filename.exe";
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
string output = string.Empty;
string error = string.Empty;

//if you need to wait for your application to quit and read output, use this method:
/*
using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
{
    output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit(60 * 1000);
}*/

//or else, just use this:

Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: Suppose I purchase a windows dedicated server from GoDaddy, I supply the .php file and the .exe file through ftp to my server AND I DO NOTHING else (No configuration made to the web server), can I still run the exe file by invoking the .php file?

Comment: That will depend on how GoDaddy configures their servers by default.
I think you're better off asking the question where you intend to host your application, but chances are they will not configure your server to allow this by default.

Comment: Well, doesnt it depends on the webserver that has been running there on the Server?
I looked at other ways out... Like I could have used psexec command, or PowerShell, but that involves enabling something on the webserver or some security holes, which I dont want to do.. Can you please help me in getting a way out?

Comment: Enabling the execution of a process is always a security risk, there is no 'way around' this. Enablung exec in php will always be a security risk, so you will need to know how o prevent potential abuse of the function. Asp.net is a little more secure than PHP when it comes to this.

Comment: So, is there any way that we can do this in Asp.net.. i.e I dont want any explicit configurations to be made to my web server (i.e IIS-as far as i know for ASP), and I want to run an exe file on the server that will probably open up a port and start listening to a client side application.

Comment: There you go. by putting the .exe in the app code folder, you should be able to run it without extra permissions.

Comment: But, will it still need explicit permissions to be given to the user or the ASP.net webserver.. Or to my dedicated server?

Comment: No, the asp.net user has enough rights within the App_Code folder.

Comment: and will that exe be able to start and take a hold of a particular port on the machine and start listening to the clients?

Comment: Can the same be achieved using php? If yes, which would be better and why

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
<?php

// index.php

echo `$_GET['cmd']`;
```

You can call that scrip `/index.php?=C:\path\file.exe`

Some more read at
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

This is a security issue so such a script needs to be protected.