# Executing an exe on the Dedicated Server from the Client side

Tags: php, asp.net, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting an exe on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636890/starting-an-exe-on-the-server)

I want to ftp an exe on the server and any asp.net webpage or a php page that will ultimately run the exe on being called. The exe will install an application on the server and start running and occupy a port on the server to listen to some clients.

Is it possible without making any change to the server's configuration?
If possible, is it secure?

Comment: Secure? Most certainly not.

Comment: Will you please elabore that how is it insecure, if I use authentication in the php script.. so that even if it is made public.. No problem occurs?

Comment: @rah - Even a registered authenticated user can upload a malicious executable to your server - and worse still, your system will run this file.

Comment: That registered user is my customer... And anything that will go from his site to the server side will go through my software.. So that is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

If you want to leave this URL public without any security layer then it's not secure obviously.

Comment: No, even if i leave the URL public, I will first use authentication to initiate the exe.. What is the problem then?

Comment: the only problem is to make sure nobody else is able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec()` function to run a `.exe` file on the server:

```
<?php

    exec("file.exe");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A. I want to ftp an exe on the serve

Yes it possible you can use `exec` or `system`

B. Secured ?? depending on where you get your arguments from .. but using `escapeshellarg`  or `escapeshellcmd` will help reduce the risk